# How to optionally add text to the email header in Laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Blade templates to configure emails. I have a header.blade that looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="header">
        <a href="{{ $url }}">
            {{ $slot }}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then in message.blade I have something like this:

```
@slot('header')
    @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
        {{ config('app.name') }}
    @endcomponent
@endslot
```

message.blade is used by all mails, so the same goes for header.blade. The problem is that I want to alter the header text ('app.name' at this moment) in a certain subset of all mails. I'm not sure what the best approach is.

I would like to have something like this:

```
@slot('header')
    @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
        {{ config('app.name') }} {{ $optionalVariable }} 
    @endcomponent
@endslot
```

Where this $optionalVariable is only set in certain emails and not in others. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap it in

```
@isset($optionalVariable)
{{ $optionalVariable }} 
@endisset
```